# Eclipse error when installing Egit

Tags: eclipse-plugin, egit

I am having some trouble trying to install the egit plugin. (installation instructions [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#eclipseinstallation))

When I try to install it I get this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: EGit Mylyn 1.1.0.201109151100-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 1.1.0.201109151100-r)
  Missing requirement: EGit Mylyn 1.1.0.201109151100-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 1.1.0.201109151100-r) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature.feature.group 3.5.0' but it could not be found.
```

It says it is missing "Egit Mylin 1.1.0" requirement. If I only select that from the previous menu I get the following error, which doesn't make much sense in my opinion... :

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: EGit Mylyn 1.1.0.201109151100-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 1.1.0.201109151100-r)
  Missing requirement: EGit Mylyn 1.1.0.201109151100-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 1.1.0.201109151100-r) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature.feature.group 3.5.0' but it could not be found
```

I have already googled it, but haven't found any helpful answer so far...

I am using Eclipse Indigo v3.7.0 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Would http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/244812/752545/#msg_752545 help?

Comment: It didn't. I have already that box checked... Thanks for the link, though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The EGit Mylyn feature requires Mylyn 3.5 or higher.  If you uncheck the EGit Mylyn feature, you should be able to complete the installation of the core EGit plugins.

The EGit Mylyn feature is optional and the core EGit feature (Eclipse EGit) will allow you to push, pull, clone, commit, etc.

You can completely ignore the EGit Mylyn feature if you don't intend to use the Git-Mylyn integration.